# CSS Как мне растянуть дочерний элемент на 100%

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="menu2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lime;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0px;
  background: blue;
}
.menu2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%; /* Неправильно :( */
  background: orange;
}
```

Как мне растянуть `.menu2` так что бы он не выезжал за родительский блок, если высота `.menu` динамическая зависит от ее контента

Comment: .block{display: flex}

Answer (score 1):

У вас ведь точно указана высота контейнера - 100vh. Выдайте такой же height детям, если нужно растянуть на всю длину.
Еще можно использовать `height: inherit` детям. Тогда они всегда будут наследовать высоту контейнера, если она явно объявлена.
А проценты ни в каком виде не работают в height, как бы ни прискорбно...

Comment: При этом, если у родителя будет `height: 100vh; padding: 20px 0; box-sizing: border-box;`, а у дочерних `height: 100vh`, то дочерние вылезут за пределы на 40px..

Comment: Гм, тогда можно пойти через calc. Детям выдаете: `height: calc(100vh - 40px)`. То бишь, вычитаете из размера контейнера padding-top и padding-bottom, которые вложенные элементы должны отступить. Получится, как нужно.